# Websocket returning "unexpected server response: 200"

Tags: ethers.js, websocket, server-side, fantom

Using ethers.js with node, I was able to connect and communicate with websockets until recently. My code did work but now I only get `Unexpected server response: 200` as response when trying to communicate with the websocket provider. As the issue occurs with the fantom websocket, I already consulted them on their discord regarding the issue, currently without response. I know the issue likely is not with the code because it worked yesterday and I didn't change anything.

Here is a minimal example to reproduce the issue:

```js
const ethers = require('ethers');

const provider = new ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider("wss://wsapi.fantom.network");
const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(" --- your private key here ---");
const account = wallet.connect(provider);

(async () => {
    const gasPrice = await provider.getGasPrice();
    console.log(`Gas price: ${gasPrice}`)
})();
```

From my research I found others seem to have this problem occur too as of late. Maybe someone knows what's the issue or how to fix it.

Appreciate any help or input!

Kind regards